# Installing Git Release in Docker

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile

If I want to install code from a release version in Github in Docker, how can I do that taking up the least space possible in the image? Currently, I've done something like:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/some/repo/archive/v1.5.1.tar.gz¬
RUN tar -xvzf v1.5.1.tar.gz¬
WORKDIR /unzipped-1.5.1/¬
RUN make; make install
```

Issue here is the final image will have the downloaded tar, the unzipped version, and everything that gets created during `make`. I don't need the vast majority of this. How do I install my library in my image without keeping all of this extra data?

Comment: See for exemple https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/ so you do all in one RUN, install, remove unneeded, clean

Answer (score 1):

This is the textbook definition of the problem that the [docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) aims to solve.

The idea is to use a separate build with the dependencies and use that docker image to build the final product.

Note that this is available only in the new versions of Docker (17.05 onwards).